# Scala-Play: How to dynamically generate a view?

Tags: scala, playframework

For a Web Service framework I am currently working on I'd like to add the possibility to test the generic Json services based on their metadata. It should be possible to dynamically build a view to let users test available Web Services. Is there a provision or some supported way to generate views dynamically in Play? if not and supposing that I simply make a template and generate it on the fly, how can this view be injected into the application at runtime?

I will be happy to see documentation/examples/pointers that could help develop such solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to create a `scala.html` and use it on somewhere  by taking the `html` created, is that?

If you create a scala template `myView.scala.html` then on `MyController` you can call `views.html.myView.render().body();` Then you would have the html created by the template.

[Template Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases#toolbar)

Comment: More less what you describe but I intend to create a `myView.scala.html` in memory on the fly is not statically on the source path and this should work also when the application is deployed ... so overwriting the `myView.scala.html` each time is not an option ...

Comment: But views in scala are 'converted' into `template.scala` files on compile time. You could create components of the page you want to use and combine them on runtime like I have said.